# Summarizing at Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, query

I like to summarize of the ID-Field with the ModelBulider because in the end I have to build a tool. The problem I have is that the field “GRIDCODE” should get in the new table comma separate. So that it is possible to see the combinations, for example the ID-Field 244 has the GRIDCODE 7, 10, 10. The Field area should get added.

[image]

Background: The Field ID-Field is from a fishnet lying over a shape with a classification “GRIDCODE” and got intersect. Now I need just a table with the ID form the fishnetcell and the combinations of the classification-code and the area. 
 Does anyone have an idea how to do this with the Modelbuilder?
Thanks a lot.

Here is the last part of the Model so far.[image]

The final table should look like this; in the field area should be the sum area from the combination.

[image]

Comment: Try tabulate area tool in Spatial Analyst. Approximate solution baseb on cell size in environment setting

Comment: I’m trying the tabulate area but it doesn’t give the output I need. So I will try Hornbydd’s way… Thanks for answering

Comment: Could you please clarify this question?  I am having a hard time understanding what your end-goal is.  Could you provide an example of the specific output you would like to produce?

Comment: Sorry, I have added a table-example for the output I wish to have in my question.

Comment: Yes I agreed I did this the same way but not similiar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood then it sounds like you want to run the [summary statistics tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) setting the case fields to be your ID field *AND* your GRIDCODE field whilst counting on GRIDCODE. This then feeds into the [pivot table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n8000000) tool.  The Pivot tool requires an *ArcInfo*(Advanced) license.

Comment: I tried it with the summary statistics tool, but I do not know what to do with the “GRIDCODE” because it shouldn’t get one of this statistics SUM_FIELD, MAX_FIELD, MIN_FIELD, RANGE_FIELD, STD_FIELD, FIRST_FIELD, LAST_FIELD, COUNT_FIELD. It should just be in a Field like 7,10,10 so that I get all the combinations. I  guess this is the step where I need the pivot table tool. Mhh, I gonna try it again… there must be a solution I hope. But in the tool pivot table I can just add one table.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain how to use the summary statistics tool correctly.

Comment: Have you experiment with the summary statics with different fields ?

Comment: Have you tried Frequency tool first and then do the summary tool ?

Comment: I did it now with the pivot table in excel, not a nice solution but it is working. I still like to do all in ArcGIS. Having a few new problems I need to do this later. so long, thanks for your answers!